# jquery $.ajax function in mvc3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to the MVC3 .NET.
I want use jquery ajax function for login. I have read some solutions in this site. But when I use these methods and write my code it has one error.
the ajax code is like below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#loginBut').click(function (e) {
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Admin/Login',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {login: username, key:password},            
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("username : " + msg.username);
        }                
    });
    $('#loginBut').blur();
});
});
```

and my admin controller with login method is like this :

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Admin/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Login(string login, string key)
    {
        return Json(new { username = login, password = key});
    }

}
```

the script is linked to the page. but after runnig and sending data I have this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:1431/Admin/Login
```

Comment: I'm surprised you got a 500, it should've been a 404 since your action is not annotated with HttpPost and you're sending a Post request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You controller action is only available to a GET request, and you are sending a POST. Annotate it with [HttpPost]:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string login, string key)
```

Also data: in $.ajax should not be an object, you are specifying application/json as the content type and the [default behavior](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is to convert the object to form-urlencoded. To use json convert it to a json string

```
data: JSON.stringify({login: username, key:password})
```

Answer (score 1):

500 error means, your code is running into some run time error. You may inspect the complete response from your server page using firebug.

You should either use `JSON.stringify` method to convert your object to JSON format

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Home","Login")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',              
    data:JSON.stringify({ login: username, key: password }),
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("username : " + msg.username);
    }
});
```

or send the real JSON data like this

```
$.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("Home","Login")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"login":username,"key":password},
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("username : " + msg.username);
    }
});
```

If you are returning JSON data from a **GET** action method, You need to mention `JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet` which specifies whether HTTP GET requests from the client are allowed.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonrequestbehavior(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonrequestbehavior%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
return Json(new { username = login, password = key},
                                                 JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
```

or mark your action method with `HttpPost` attribute.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string login, string key)
{
    //to do :return something/redirect
}
```

In the case of a Login, always use `HttpPost` decorated action methods.